# Grails/GORM DomainClass.where{callable} produces wrong results

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, grails-orm, criteria

```
DomainClass.where{
    user.id == currentUser.id
}.list()
```

so, I have a **DomainClass**, that *has a user*;

Technically, this **should** return a List< DomainClass > which share the **currentUser** *(which is not null)*.

So, for instance, I have **two** entries as such in my database, and *five more, with other users*.

My question is:

**WHY, sometimes, on server restart, this simple where produces incorrect results?**

By incorrect results, I mean **the List< DomainClass > contains ALL DomainClass instances** (7, to be precise with the numbers mentioned before).

If I try to evaluate this in IntelliJ, I get the same, and if I use *DomainClass.withCriteria* it works. But why does it happen in the first place?

- will update with further info, if needed.

  #### Update

This would be the alternative query.

```
DomainModel.withCriteria {
    user {
        eq 'id', currentUser.id
    }
}
```

When this happens, this evaluates to an ArrayList with 2 entries; while the other has 7. It is true that the query inside is more complex, but it fails for even this simplified version.

Also, grails version is 2.3.6.

Comment: Are you saying the equivalent criteria query works every time? If so, please post that query.

Comment: It does work when, after restart, the 'where' doesn't produce the correct results. The interesting part is, if I take a look at the DetachedCriteria which is created, under criteria I do find exactly what I'm querying for (id of user should be a given value), but that constraint isn't respected.

Comment: Have you compared the SQL calls being made to the database? I know in some database, such as PostgreSQL, it's possible to see the most recent SQL statement per database connection.

Comment: No, unfortunately I have not. I need to check this for MySQL; and wait, until this bug resurfaces.

Comment: Hello Stefan, I ran into the same problem recently (grails 2.4.4) and it seems a massive problem. This happened randomly when the server was restarted (no deploy of a new release, not changing anything else, only restart). I can connect to the console and see that 'where' queries aren't working, all records are returned. With a proper stop/start it worked. Also I occasionally lose injected services in quartz job but I think it's not related. Did you find a solution or a root cause ?

Comment: Hello @mizar; the only 'fix' was replacing all the `where`s with `withCriteria`s (or, `createCriteria().list()` - which is pretty much the same thing, but `createCriteria()` is a bit more versatile, depending on what you want to do). As of this moment, I haven't found a root cause for it. Regarding services, it has happened, occasionally, to get null pointer exceptions, **sometimes** - the service was actually null - if it's the same issue with your own, another temporary fix was to make a `getServiceName` method, and having a try/catch, then returning the service